# How do I stop anyone being able to update anybody's details?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `UpdateView` to allow a user to update their details:

```
#views.py
class Profile(UpdateView):
    model = Freelancer
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'surname', 'university', 'biography']
    template_name = "freelancestudent/profile.html"
```

A user can get their profile through the `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Profile.as_view(), name="profile"),
```

The base template contains a hyperlink

```
<a href="/profile/{{user.id}}">Profile |</a>
```

So a user with ID 3 clicks the `Profile` link and the address bar reads `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/3/`, they can edit their profile, save it and all is great.

However, if the user augments the URL to a valid `user.id` they can edit their details.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to override the `get_queryset` method of the view, and filter based on `self.request.user`.

```
class Profile(UpdateView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Profile, self).get_queryset()
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return queryset.none()
        else:
            return queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
```

The `user.is_authenticated()` check handles users that are not logged in. If the view uses a login required decorator or mixin, then it isn't necessary.